# How do the executable scripts in Perl modules get the correct shebang line?

Tags: path, installation, perl-module

Generally, when a Perl module installs an executable script, it somehow changes the `#!/usr/bin/perl` line to point to the appropriate Perl path. For example, if I used the perl installed at `/usr/local/bin/perl` to install the module, then the shebang line will be changed to `#!/usr/local/bin/perl`, so that the installed script will always use the version of perl that installed it.

What does this, and how can I do it in my own modules that install scripts?

#### Edit

Note that I am specifically talking about executable perl scripts that are distributed as part of a Perl module. Since a module is installed to a specific version of Perl, any scripts installed by that module must use that same version, so <strike>`#!/usr/bin/env perl`</strike> is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [http://metacpan.org/pod/ExtUtils::MakeMaker](http://metacpan.org/pod/ExtUtils%3a%3aMakeMaker)

EXE_FILES

Ref to array of executable files. The files will be copied to the INST_SCRIPT directory. Make realclean will delete them from there again.

If your executables start with something like #!perl or #!/usr/bin/perl MakeMaker will change this to the path of the perl 'Makefile.PL' was invoked with so the programs will be sure to run properly even if perl is not in /usr/bin/perl.